# C programming pattern

Tags: c

i needed code for this pattern.

```
1
2 4 6
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8 10
1 3 5 7 9 11 13
```

i tried it , but was not able to make it up my code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int i,j,k=1;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
        printf("%d",k);
        k+=2;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```

This c pattern has 1 extra integer in the 2nd row and last row. Help would be appreciated

Comment: What does *"How do make it 1 and 2 constantly"* mean exactly?

Comment: posting the expected output would be helpful

Comment: Every row has 1 and 2 consequently at the beginning .

Comment: @yano output required is written at the starting of the question

Comment: @Akki expected or actual? My eyes to tired to compile

Comment: You should reset `k` before entering the inner loop. Make it `1` if `i` is odd and 2 otherwise.

Comment: And what output are you getting with your current code?

Comment: @HRgiger actual required . Valid pattern , i didn't make it up by myself .

Comment: @MOehm what about the extra integers in the 2nd row and the last row ?

Comment: @DBPriGuy 1 3 5 7 9 and so on . but tuff part is to figure out the fix for extra digits in the 2nd and last row . There is one extra integer.

Comment: It is not Design Pattern

Comment: @sung i get it)

Answer (score 2):

The (main) problem is that you're not resetting `k` at each new iteration of the outer loop. Also, the extra integer at the end of the 2<sup>nd</sup> and last rows require an ugly condition in the inner loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(int argc, 
     char** argv)
{
    unsigned int i, j, k,
                 F = 6u;  /* number of rows + 1 */

    for(i=0u; i<F; ++i)
    {
        k = i % 2u + 1u;

        for(j=0u; j < i + (i>=2u) + (i==F-1); ++j)
        {
            printf("%u ",k);
            k += 2u;
        }

        puts("");
    }

}
```

Comment: The other kink is that the required output shows that the first row should have 1 element, and the second row 3, which breaks with the simple loop pattern

Comment: Still that won't solve it because of 1 extra digit in the second and last row

Comment: @DBPriGuy true. The OP isn't very clear on ... much of the detail.

Comment: @Akki see my update; the loop condition in the inner loop has to be changed as well

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis    Can you explain me what is going on with the code ? i see conditional operators in the second for loop . Quite confusing